# Mantis email notifications, Outlook conversations

Tags: outlook, mantis

I get (too) many Mantis email notifications per day in my Outlook.
Each ticket can produce many notifications every day.
All the notifications for a single ticket have the same subject:

```
[MyProject 00012345]: Title of the ticket
```

In my Outloook, sometimes the notifications for a single ticket are grouped as a conversation, but sometimes they are kept as separate messages, even when sharing the same subject (and obviously the same sender).
I cannot figure out why this happens.
Please explain me why it happens, so that I can get one conversation per Mantis ticket.

Comment: compare the fields: `Subject` and `Thread-Topic` of the messages using this tutorial: https://superuser.com/questions/476940/outlook-2013-view-raw-message-source-of-an-email

Comment: I see that Mantis notifications don't have a Thread-Topic, while other emails do.
Please make your comment an answer, I will test and if this solves the problem I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

compare the fields: `Subject` and `Thread-Topic` of the messages using this tutorial: https://superuser.com/questions/476940/outlook-2013-view-raw-message-source-of-an-email

Comment: I am still investigating, but it appears that "Thread-Index" might be more accurate:

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=411601

Comment: For future readers: test will take longer, so I cannot confirm that it is indeed correct